# Form submission using Ajax in the Laravel blade file and need to handle same errors

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use Ajax for form submission in a Laravel blade file.

```
<div class="shop-container">
    <form class="" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/shop') }}">

        <div class="form-group @hasError('from_name')">
            <label class="control-label">From Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from-name" name="from_name" value="{{ old('from_name', shop_setting('shop.from_name')) }}">
            @error('from_name')
        </div>

        <div class="form-group @hasError('company_name')">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company-name" name="company_name" value="{{ old('company_name', shop_setting('shop.company_name')) }}">
            @error('company_name')
        </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Is it possible with Ajax to post it and still handle the errors the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can handle the same errors, but not in the same way, not if you wish to use ajax *instead* of a server-fed Laravel blade error route.  But jQuery error handling is pretty easy and elegant as well.

Look into [Jquery Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for more information.